# Need help getting ability to disable access protection on VirusScan console

Tags: windows-7, lock

My computer (k12 but my dad and I are techies so we are safe) comes with McAfee and I am trying to get rid of it because I prefer Avast. Anyways, k12 makes sure you cannot easily remove it. I have looked at a lot of solutions but all of them say: "Go to Start, programs, McAfee, VirusScan console. Then right click on on Access Protection, properties and disable it."

I can't do that! It won't give me permission. I can do properties but I can't uncheck the boxes. Here is what I have done:

I went to msconfig and disabled all McAfee in startup. Ran everything as admin. Tried to stop McAfee processes and then disable them in msconfig, got denied.

What can I do? And please don't suggest VirusScan Console as the first thing I do. I can't edit **anything** in there.

Comment: Uninstall it in control panel>programs and features.

Comment: So you are looking to just disable this feature or McAfee overall?  Are you attempting to disable it as a user in the Administrator user group?

Comment: Here is my guess.  This computer isn't your actual property, based on my research it is an education tool, which means the actual Administrator is somebody other then yourself or your father.  This basically means you won't be able to uninstall McAfee.  [McAfee Web Protection - Enable/Disable](http://help.k12.com/support-topics/computer-equipment/set-k%C2%B9%C2%B2-issued-computer-equipment/mcafee-web-protection-enable-and)

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the "Access Protection" listing, then UNCHECK the box in the lower left that says: Prevent McAfee Services From Being stopped", then click on "Apply", then UNCHECK the box in the upper left with says: "Enable Access Protection".

Remember though, if you're using ePO on your system, the settings change will generally only remain until the computer is rebooted.

Answer (score -1):

I just found a way today I also use a k12 computer they fill them full of bloatware and other things that slow them down but I found a program that actually removes the McAfee things its called IOBIT UNINSTALLER its free btw

Comment: This answer would be better if you would say (1) where to get this software and (2) how to use it.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.